# When to call this() and when to call super() in java?

Tags: java

Can any one please tell me what is the difference between super() call and this() call in java constructors?

Comment: A google-able question . super() is for calling superclass' constructor .  this() is current class

Comment: `this` refers to constructor of (guess what...) current (this) class. `super` refers to constructor of superclass.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super()` calls the parent constructor of the class and `this()` calls the constructor defined within the class.

```
//Example of super()
class parent
{
  parent()
  {

  }
}
class child()
{
   child()
   {
      super();   //Go to parent class constructor
   }
}


//Example of this    
class test
{
    test()
    {
       this("a");  //go to test one argument constructor within the test class
    }
    test(String a)
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

super() means the super class (parent) and this() means the current class.

Answer (score 2):

`this()` calls another constructor for the same class. In this case the 0 argument one.

`super()` calls the constructor for the super class.

Answer (score 2):

super() calls no-argument constructor from superclass and this() calls no-arg constructor from the current class.

Answer (score 1):

super() refers to the base/parent class.  Can be used in constructor to invoke parent constructor but must be done in the declaration of the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It means you are delegating part of the object construction to another constructor, being `super()` a constructor defined in a superclass and `this()` a constructor defined in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

The `super()` is for calling superclass' constructor . `this()` refers to the  current class .

Here are good SO-links.

[this and super in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883594/this-and-super-in-java?lq=1)

[Difference between "this" and"super" keywords in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023344/difference-between-this-andsuper-keywords-in-java?rq=1)