# differentiate between super and this

Tags: java

I am trying to find proof for the statement - keyword `super` is the reference to parent class just like keyword `this` is the reference to current class.

I am trying multilevel Inheritance in Java A->B->C: class A is grand parent, class B is parent, class C is child.

I have a variable `X` declared in all three classes with values respectively (A:x=100,B:x=200,C:x=300)

In the child class constructor I am printing values. However the casting isn't working for `super` keyword whereas it's working for `this` keyword.

`((A)super).x` is not working, but `((A)this).x` is working.

```
class A {
    int x = 100;
}

class B extends A {
    int x = 200;
}

public class C extends B {
    int x = 300;
    public C () {
        System.out.println(this.x); //OP = 300
        System.out.println(super.x); // OP = 200
        System.out.println(((A)this).x);// OP = 100
        System.out.println(((A)super).x); // Giving Compile time Error.. Why?
        B reftoB = new B();
        System.out.println(((A)reftoB).x);  // OP = 100
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C t1= new C();
    }
}
```

I expect the output of `System.out.println(((A)super).x)` is `100`, but it is giving a compile time error.

So my question is if `super` is a reference to the parent class then why isn't type casting working on it?

Comment: It's just not valid syntax. `super` can't be used that way. It can only be used in a direct field access/method invocation expression, with none of that attempt to cast.

Comment: `super` refers to the same instance as `this`. What you're trying to do doesn't make sense.

Comment: `super` is not 'the reference to the parent class'. It is a keyword which allows you to refer to an inherited field or method. Nothing more.

Answer (score 4):

Use of `Super` Keyword:

1. `super()` can be used to refer immediate parent class instance
   variable.
2. `super()` can be used to invoke immediate parent class method.
3. `super()` can be used to invoke immediate parent class constructor.

Your compiler is a compilation error for `(A)super).x` , because it is not a valid statement, moreover we don't use it this way, ontop of all  **It violates encapsulation**, you should not able to bypass parent class. In every definition of `super()` you will find something mentioned as **current parent class**, but what you are trying to do here is ***bypassing* current parent**.

**Now coming to your problem:**

```
x                // Field x in class C
this.x           // Field x in class C
super.x          // Field x in class B
((B)this).x      // Field x in class B
((A)this).x      // Field x in class A
super.super.x    // Illegal; does not refer to x in class A
((A)super).x     // Illegal as well as compilation error
```

**If you still want to access variables like what you intented then use something like below:**

```
t1.x              // Field x of class C 
((B)t1).x         // Field x of class B
((A)t1).x         // Field x of class A
```

*Note*: `t1` is your class C instance.

Comment: ```super()``` and ```super``` are rather different things.  The former is a constructor call, the latter operates so as to modify the usual name resolution algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to why `this` can be cast but `super` cannot is the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2883613/1371329) to the question why `this` can be passed as a method argument but `super` cannot: namely, because `this` is defined by the JLS as a [Primary Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8) but `super` is not.

Comment: Upvote for the (indirect) pointer to the language spec; section 15.11.2  in the JLS for Java SE 11, for anyone else interested.

Answer (score -1):

The `super` keyword refers to a class parent, and `this` keyword refers to the class you are in. Let's create a parent class to start the demonstration:

```
public class ParentClass{

  private int justANumber;

  public ParentClass(int justANumber){
    this.justANumber = justANumber;
  }

}
```

Notice how the `this` keyword is used here, which is telling "Hey, assign the justANumber value to THIS class attribute also called justANumber". Let's create a subclass for this parent class now:

```
public class Subclass extends ParentClass{

  // You don't need to declare the justANumber variable, cause it's from the parent

  public Subclass(int justANumber){
    super(justANumber);
  }

  public showNumber(){
    return this.justANumber;
  }

}
```

The `super()` method calls the parent constructor, which need an `int` value on the first place, so you pass it as an argument. Now see how the `showNumber()` method returns `this.justANumber`? Why? that's because when the `super()` method is called, the parent class automatically delegates his variables to the subclass, so in this case, `Subclass` can now say that `justANumber` is HIS variable, being able to use the `this` keyword. Hope you now understand de difference.

Comment: The original post does not use the superclass constructor call ```super()``` anywhere.  It uses, and is asking about, the superclass access keyword ```super```.